# Programmatically generate a .bna file

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

So I know how to use `composer archive create -t dir -n .` and found its code [over here](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/packages/composer-cli/lib/cmds/archive/lib/create.js). While doing unit tests I am able to generate the businessNetworkDefinition and run them using `composer-embedded` but now I am trying to generate a `.bna` file programmatically. Can't seem to find the API that allows it to happen.

I have tried [using this](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/api/common-businessnetworkdefinition#todirectory) but it just throws an error saying `unable to find lastIndexOf()`.

Use case is, a `.cto` file is edited and now a new `.bna` file must be created.

Answer (score 0):

So this [particular line](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/packages/composer-cli/lib/cmds/archive/lib/create.js#L102) solves the problem for me. I was using version `0.20.x`. I changed the version to `0.19.14` and edited part of the code. Seems there might be an issue with `0.20.x`

My package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "composer-client": "^0.19.14",
    "composer-common": "^0.19.14",
    "composer-admin": "^0.19.14",
    "composer-connector-embedded": "^0.19.14",
    "compression": "^1.7.3",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "helmet": "^3.15.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.10",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.3"
  }
```

And the code

```
const BusinessNetworkDefinition = require('composer-common').BusinessNetworkDefinition;
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

async function main() {
  const businessNetworkDefinition = await BusinessNetworkDefinition.fromDirectory(path.resolve(__dirname, '../tests/chaincode'));
  businessNetworkName = businessNetworkDefinition.getName();
  console.log(businessNetworkName);
  fs.writeFileSync('my-special.bna', await businessNetworkDefinition.toArchive());
};
main();
```

The `chaincode` folder is

```
- chaincode
  - lib
    - logic.js
  - models
    - base.cto
  - package.json
  - permissions.acl
  - queries.qry
```

Hope this helps anyone trying to achieve the same!